# MariaDB transaction commits only last insert

Tags: database, transactions, doctrine, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB 10.4.8 and there is something wrong with transactions.
The problem:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO zone (code) VALUES ('test1');
INSERT INTO zone (code) VALUES ('test2');
COMMIT;
```

If I execute a transaction like this, for example, only **test2** record will be inserted.
What the hell is happening, maybe I need to configure something. With DB behaving like that, I cannot use Doctrine's `persist()/flush()` functionality properly.

Comment: There are two bug reports for MariaDB which can be potentially related to your problem. Both haven't been reproduced internally so far, so it could be very useful if you could add there whatever information you have, especially a complete test case (including the table creation), configuration file, and the environment information. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20354 -- symptoms are very similar to yours, but it also uses `LOCK TABLE` which you didn't mention, and might be system-specific. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20683 - no information at all yet.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=c844a5d01e127c34bcaf8e2e36c1455f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs as described if MariaDB 10.x server started with `use-stat-tables` is missing some (or all) of statistical tables `mysql.table_stats`, `mysql.index_stats`, `mysql.column_stats`.

The most likely reason for the missing tables is that the instance was upgraded from MariaDB 5.5 or crossgraded from MySQL or Percona server, and `mysql_upgrade` was not run or did not succeed. You might not even be aware that the instance had an old server before, especially if it's installed as a part of another product.

Another possibility is that some third-party products install a pre-created database, and this database was pre-created with a server version unaware of statistical tables.

In either case, a server started on such databases probably complains upon startup in the error log about a wrong structure of mysql.event table and some other missing tables. However, on package installations the error log is typically written by default to `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`, so non-fatal errors are often missed.

All 10.x versions have the problem, but 10.4 is affected most because it has `use_stat_tables=PREFERABLY` by defaullt.

The bug is tracked within [MDEV-20354](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20354).

Meanwhile, **the solution is to run `mysql_upgrade`** (with `--force` if necessary).

Comment: You are right. The problem was faulty tables created by Doctrine, which I am using. I had specified MariaDB version in Doctrine configuration, but apparently, it was treated in a wrong way. I removed MariaDB version from configuration as it is optional, ran `mysql_upgrade` and everything is cool since then, new tables are created without such problems.
Thank you for detailed explanation, I hope that will be useful for others, also :)